# Replace object on heap?

Tags: c#, object, reference

Maybe this is real simple or breaking all the rules or maybe I just dont know what its called so I cant find it.

Anyway, I want to be able to replace an entire object on the heap. I've added a small code sample to show what I want to do, and a way of doing it, but I just want to know if there is a more elegant way?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BasicObjectTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Test> testList = new List<Test>
            {
                new Test {Value=1,NiceString="First" },
                new Test {Value=2,NiceString="Second" },
                new Test {Value=3,NiceString="Third" }

            };

            var replacementTestClass = new Test { Value = 2, NiceString = "NEW" };
            EasyWay(testList, replacementTestClass);

            var correctTestClass = testList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == 2);
            Console.WriteLine(correctTestClass.NiceString); //Expecting "Forth"
            Console.ReadLine();

            HardWay(testList, replacementTestClass);

            correctTestClass = testList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == 2);
            Console.WriteLine(correctTestClass.NiceString);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void HardWay(List<Test> testList, Test replacementTestClass)
        {
            //This will work!
            var secondTestClass = testList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == 2);

            CopyPropertiesUsingPropertyInfo(secondTestClass, replacementTestClass);



        }

        private static void CopyPropertiesUsingPropertyInfo(Test secondTestClass, Test replacementTestClass)
        {
            foreach(var pi in secondTestClass.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                pi.SetValue(secondTestClass, pi.GetValue(replacementTestClass, null));
            }



        }

        private static void EasyWay(List<Test> testList, Test replacementTestClass)
        {
            //This wont work, but I want it to!

            var secondTestClass = testList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == 2);

            secondTestClass = replacementTestClass;


        }
    }
}
```

and my Test object

```
class Test
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string NiceString { get; set; }

}
```

There must be a more elegant way of doing this? 
I know why the first alternative does not work: I just change the object reference for that variable.

Update:
Using this thinking I understood it for a long time I tested this now thinking it would work, but the test fails. Why? Didnt I replace the object so that every object using it should use the new object? See complete code below

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var main = new Main { Property = 1 };

        var dependent = new Dependent(main);

        void ChangeRef(ref Main Oldmain, Main newMain)
        {
            Oldmain = newMain;

        }

        ChangeRef(ref main, new Main { Property = 5 });

        Assert.AreEqual(5,dependent.Main.Property);
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public int Property { get; set; }


}

public class Dependent
{
    public Dependent(Main main)
    {
        Main = main;
    }

    public Main Main { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There must be a more elegant way of doing this?

There is one basic thing you're missing. When you search for the object in the list, and one is found, you get back a *copy of the reference pointing to that object*. This means that when you alter it, you're only altering the copy. The original reference in the list is still pointing to that same old object instance.

> but what if I didnt have a list. I just had the object reference in a
>   variable?

Then you could use the [`ref` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) to pass the reference type *by reference*:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var test = new Test { Value = 1, NiceString = "First" };
    var newTest = new Test { Value = 2, NiceString = "AlteredTest!" };

    UpdateTest(ref test, newTest);
    Console.WriteLine(test.NiceString); // "AlteredTest!"
}

public static void UpdateTest(ref Test originalTest, Test other)
{
    originalTest = other;
}
```

Comment: I did not know that about passing objects as ref. I've mearly used it for value types.

Comment: @Erik83 Reference types also get passed ***by value***. The difference is that the value is actually a reference pointing to an address in virtual memory, and not the actual bytes like with a value type.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to approach this is with the proverbial "extra level of indirection".

Instead of storing the objects in the list, you store wrapper objects instead. The wrapper object provides an "Item" field which points to the actual object. Then you can update the "Item" field to point it at the new object.

A simple generic wrapper class could look like this:

```
class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Item;

    public Wrapper(T item)
    {
        Item = item;
    }

    public static implicit operator Wrapper<T>(T item)
    {
        return new Wrapper<T>(item);    
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Test
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string NiceString { get; set; }
    }

    class Wrapper<T>
    {
        public T Item;

        public Wrapper(T item)
        {
            Item = item;
        }

        public static implicit operator Wrapper<T>(T item)
        {
            return new Wrapper<T>(item);    
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testList = new List<Wrapper<Test>>
            {
                new Test {Value = 1, NiceString = "First"},
                new Test {Value = 2, NiceString = "Second"},
                new Test {Value = 3, NiceString = "Third"}
            };

            var replacementTestClass = new Test { Value = 2, NiceString = "NEW" };
            EasyWay(testList, replacementTestClass);

            var correctTestClass = testList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item.Value == 2);
            Console.WriteLine(correctTestClass.Item.NiceString); //Expecting "New"
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void EasyWay(List<Wrapper<Test>> testList, Test replacementTestClass)
        {
            var secondTestClass = testList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item.Value == 2);
            secondTestClass.Item = replacementTestClass;
        }
    }
}
```